# iconv not complete convert to utf8

Tags: linux, iconv

When I converted my text on this site, be converted correctly:
http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx
I choose source 'Windows-1252' and target 'utf-8'.
See it in the screenshot below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pn4E.png

But when I convert with the following code, Some letters are not converted and the text is disrupted.

```
iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t WINDOWS-1252 < mytext.txt > fixed_mytext.txt
```

A phrase that should be converted:

```
Ø¢Ù…ÙˆØ²Ø´ Ùˆ Ù†Ø±Ù… Ø§ÙØ²Ø§Ø±Ù‡Ø§ÛŒ ØªØ¹Ù…ÛŒØ± Ù…Ø§Ù†ÛŒØªÙˆØ±
```

If true, the convert should be this phrase:

```
 آموزش و نرم افزارهای تعمیر مانیتور
```

plese help me. thank you

Comment: It is useless to post text which is not in UTF-8 here. It will be disrupted and no one will be able to reproduce your error. Post a hexadecimal dump of your data  (`od -t x1 myfile.txt`).

Comment: my tex in hexadecimal:
http://www.todaymagazine.ir/mytext-hex.txt

Comment: (1) If you are posting a link to a file, post a link to the original file, not to a hex dump! (2) The file is large and most of it seems to be ASCII, please post only the relevant fragment. (3) I have  tried what you just did and it worked for me (I copied and pasted your phrase from the question, not from the linked file).. You have UTF-8 text reinterpreted as Windows1252 and converted to UTF-8 again. You have to convert from UTF-8 to Windows-1252 *and then use the result as UTF-8*.

Comment: thank you. My problem with the letter 'ف' that is not converted. my orginal file : http://www.todaymagazine.ir/forum.txt

Comment: relevant fragment: http://www.todaymagazine.ir/relevant-fragment.txt

Comment: after convert (? is ف): آموزش و نرم ا�زارهای تعمیر مانیتور

Comment: The file is converted incorrectly because ف in UTF-8 is 0xd9 0x81 and 0x81 is not present in Windows-1252 code page. This character is now lost.There is nothing `iconv` can do. You have to fix it manually.

Comment: I'm grateful. My file is very large. How do I convert it manually?

Comment: Sorry it's not lost, it's still there. The offending code sequence is `0xc3 0x99 0xc2 0x81`.  You can fix it with a sed script.

Comment: can you write to me for an example for sed? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original text was in UTF-8. It got mistakenly interpreted as a text in Windows-1252 and converted from Windows-1252 to UTF-8. This should have never been done. To undo the damage we need to convert the file from UTF-8 to Windows-1252, and then just treat it as a UTF-8 file.

There's a problem however. The letter ف is encoded in UTF-8 as `0xd9 0x81`, and the code `0x81` is not a part of Windows1252.

Luckily when the first erroneous conversion was made, the character was not lost or replaced with a question mark. It got converted to a control character `0xc2 0x81`.

The `0xd9` code is in Windows1252, it's the letter `Ù`, which in UTF-8 is `0xc3 0x99`. So the final byte sequence for ف in the converted file is `0xc3 0x99 0xc2 0x81`.

We can just replace with something ASCII-friendly with a `sed` script, make an inverse conversion, and then replace it back with ف.

```
LANG=C sed $'s/\xc3\x99\xc2\x81/===FE===/g' forum.txt  | \
       iconv -f utf8 -t cp1252 | \
       sed $'s/===FE===/\xd9\x81/g'
```

The result is the original file encoded in UTF-8.

(make sure that `===FE===` is not used in the text first!)

Comment: Only instead of "utf8", should "utf-8" be used. :)